# php remove child node but keep its children

Tags: php, xml

I use this code:
I'm trying to remove the categoryPath node but keep its children (all the name tags)
It currently leaves the categoryPath, but I'm looking for advice as to how I can remove the categoryPath node, but keeps its children.

```
<?php

// load up your XML
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('book.xml');

// Find all elements you want to replace. Since your data is really simple,
// you can do this without much ado. Otherwise you could read up on XPath.
 // See http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php
$elements = $xml->getElementsByTagName('category');
$categoryPath = $xml->getElementsByTagName('categoryPath');
// WARNING: $elements is a "live" list -- it's going to reflect the structure
// of the document even as we are modifying it! For this reason, it's
// important to write the loop in a way that makes it work correctly in the
// presence of such "live updates".


while($elements->length) {
$category = $elements->item(0); 
$name = $category->firstChild; // implied by the structure of your XML 

// replace the category with just the name 
$category->parentNode->replaceChild($name, $category);
```

}

```
// final result:
$result = $xml->saveXML();
echo $result;
?>
```

But it doesn't remove the categoryPath node

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
<product>
<bestBuyItemId>531670</bestBuyItemId>
<modelNumber>METRA ELECTRONICS/MOBILE AUDIO</modelNumber>
<categoryPath>
<name>ddd</name>
<name>Car, Marine &amp; GPS</name>
<name>Car Installation Parts</name>
<name>Deck Installation Parts</name>
<name>Antennas &amp; Adapters</name>
</categoryPath>
</product>

</products>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in the following line :

```
$elements = $xml->getElementsByTagName('category');
```

What node is supposed to be category? I don't see any category node in your xml file.

Then, this code :

```
while($elements->length) {
    $category = $elements->item(0); 
    $name = $category->firstChild; // implied by the structure of your XML 

    // replace the category with just the name 
    $category->parentNode->replaceChild($name, $category); 
}
```

cannot work for sure because `$elements` is empty.

What you want is to select all `name` nodes, then append them to the `product` node. Something like :

```
foreach ( $xml->getElementsByTagName('product') as $product ) {
    foreach( $product->getElementsByTagName('name') as $name ) {
        $product->appendChild( $name );
    }
    $product.removeChild( $xml->getElementsByTagName('categoryPath')->item(0) );
}
```

Comment: It was a node that I removed.

Comment: Can you give me an idea of how to do that?

Comment: Updated answer with an example. Php is far gone from memory, might have some syntax error in it...

Comment: It worked. Thanks for that. But it is only appending 3 of the name tags? Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: It should append all name nodes, can you update your question with whole code?